# laravel button in blade template submitted multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have some code in a blade template which create some forms and buttons, see below

```
<div class="element1">
<div class="text1">
<form action="{{ route("progressSheetDynamic") }}" method="post" id= "add">
<input name="increment" value="increment" type="hidden"> </input>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value= {{$activities}} >
<button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton" id= {{$activities}} > + </button>
</form>

{{ $count  }} / {{  ($goal/5) }}
<form action="{{route("progressSheetDynamic") }}" method="post" id="delete">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="delete">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value= {{$activities}}>
<button type="submit" class="styleHover styleButton"> - </button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

I use @include_layouts("template file") 3 times in my view file to create the buttons 3 different times. When I click one button I want one ajax request to fire. Instead what is currently happening is that one button click shows up as there button clicks and submits the ajax request 3 different times.
Here is the relevant javascript code in the blade file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#add').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function(response){
console.log(data);
});
});
});
```

I have tried many different things like using jQuery to change the button to be disabled after one click and returning false at the end of the jQuery function.

However, in each case one click is being read as three different clicks. So the data is logged to the console three times. Is there any way to make it so that when I click one button it only registers as one click instead of 3?

Comment: I am already using an id though, {{$activities}} is a variable that comes from the view and this results in a different id for each button. How would I use a class to fix my problem?

Comment: use a class for the forms not a id

Comment: I have tried this for the forms it did not work. I have also tried changing the ids of the buttons to classes and did not work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the ajax on the form click, try it on the button click

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.styleButton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
$.post('progressSheetDynamic', data).done(function(response){
console.log(data);
});
});
});
```

Comment: This also gives me the same result unfortunately

Comment: put this code outside any loop and at the bottom of the page

Comment: I did this and got the same result. Just to be clear the button in the blade file is being recreated three time in the view. I was getting it to work without ajax.

Comment: where its this code placed in the partial or in the main view?

Comment: Its in the partial. I got it to work without a partial file by putting all of the code in the main view. But now I am trying to use the partial file to avoid re writing the same code multiple times

Comment: put the js in the main template man ,your loop is looping the js code as well,didn't you read my first comment?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood what you said. It works now thanks